# Importing ar.js using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ar.js

I am working on a project based on three.js, and I am trying to add Augmented Reality support using ar.js library. The project is based on Node and bundled with Webpack, with Babel loader.
Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
        },
      ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'three': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/build/three.min.js'),
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Webpack Output",
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'THREE': 'three',
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    open: true
  },

};
```

Before adding any code I try to import the ar.js library, from local folder added to the project after having it downloaded from official github repository:
https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js

When I build the project I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/AR.js-master/three.js/build/ar.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /webpack-demo/src/AR.js-master/three.js/build/ar.js: Identifier '_malloc' has already been declared (19:519)

  17 | 
  18 | // EMSCRIPTEN_END_ASM
> 19 | (Module.asmGlobalArg,Module.asmLibraryArg,buffer);var _i64Subtract=Module["_i64Subtract"]=asm["_i64Subtract"];var __GLOBAL__sub_I_bind_cpp=Module["__GLOBAL__sub_I_bind_cpp"]=asm["__GLOBAL__sub_I_bind_cpp"];var _fflush=Module["_fflush"]=asm["_fflush"];var __GLOBAL__sub_I_ARToolKitJS_cpp=Module["__GLOBAL__sub_I_ARToolKitJS_cpp"]=asm["__GLOBAL__sub_I_ARToolKitJS_cpp"];var _i64Add=Module["_i64Add"]=asm["_i64Add"];var _memset=Module["_memset"]=asm["_memset"];var runPostSets=Module["runPostSets"]=asm["runPostSets"];var _malloc=Module["_malloc"]=asm["_malloc"];var _memcpy=Module["_memcpy"]=asm["_memcpy"];var ___getTypeName=Module["___getTypeName"]=asm["___getTypeName"];var _bitshift64Lshr=Module["_bitshift64Lshr"]=asm["_bitshift64Lshr"];var _free=Module["_free"]=asm["_free"];var ___errno_location=Module["___errno_location"]=asm["___errno_location"];var _bitshift64Shl=Module["_bitshift64Shl"]=asm["_bitshift64Shl"];var dynCall_iiii=Module["dynCall_iiii"]=asm["dynCall_iiii"];var dynCall_viiiii=Module["dynCall_viiiii"]=asm["dynCall_viiiii"];var dynCall_dii=Module["dynCall_dii"]=asm["dynCall_dii"];var dynCall_vid=Module["dynCall_vid"]=asm["dynCall_vid"];var dynCall_di=Module["dynCall_di"]=asm["dynCall_di"];var dynCall_i=Module["dynCall_i"]=asm["dynCall_i"];var dynCall_vi=Module["dynCall_vi"]=asm["dynCall_vi"];var dynCall_vii=Module["dynCall_vii"]=asm["dynCall_vii"];var dynCall_ii=Module["dynCall_ii"]=asm["dynCall_ii"];var dynCall_viii=Module["dynCall_viii"]=asm["dynCall_viii"];var dynCall_v=Module["dynCall_v"]=asm["dynCall_v"];var dynCall_viid=Module["dynCall_viid"]=asm["dynCall_viid"];var dynCall_iiiii=Module["dynCall_iiiii"]=asm["dynCall_iiiii"];var dynCall_viiiiii=Module["dynCall_viiiiii"]=asm["dynCall_viiiiii"];var dynCall_iii=Module["dynCall_iii"]=asm["dynCall_iii"];var dynCall_viiii=Module["dynCall_viiii"]=asm["dynCall_viiii"];Runtime.stackAlloc=asm["stackAlloc"];Runtime.stackSave=asm["stackSave"];Runtime.stackRestore=asm["stackRestore"];Runtime.establishStackSpace=asm["establishStackSpace"];Runtime.setTempRet0=asm["setTempRet0"];Runtime.getTempRet0=asm["getTempRet0"];function ExitStatus(status){this.name="ExitStatus";this.message="Program terminated with exit("+status+")";this.status=status}ExitStatus.prototype=new Error;ExitStatus.prototype.constructor=ExitStatus;var initialStackTop;var preloadStartTime=null;var calledMain=false;dependenciesFulfilled=function runCaller(){if(!Module["calledRun"])run();if(!Module["calledRun"])dependenciesFulfilled=runCaller};Module["callMain"]=Module.callMain=function callMain(args){assert(runDependencies==0,"cannot call main when async dependencies remain! (listen on __ATMAIN__)");assert(__ATPRERUN__.length==0,"cannot call main when preRun functions remain to be called");args=args||[];ensureInitRuntime();var argc=args.length+1;function pad(){for(var i=0;i<4-1;i++){argv.push(0)}}var argv=[allocate(intArrayFromString(Module["thisProgram"]),"i8",ALLOC_NORMAL)];pad();for(var i=0;i<argc-1;i=i+1){argv.push(allocate(intArrayFromString(args[i]),"i8",ALLOC_NORMAL));pad()}argv.push(0);argv=allocate(argv,"i32",ALLOC_NORMAL);try{var ret=Module["_main"](argc,argv,0);exit(ret,true)}catch(e){if(e instanceof ExitStatus){return}else if(e=="SimulateInfiniteLoop"){Module["noExitRuntime"]=true;return}else{if(e&&typeof e==="object"&&e.stack)Module.printErr("exception thrown: "+[e,e.stack]);throw e}}finally{calledMain=true}};function run(args){args=args||Module["arguments"];if(preloadStartTime===null)preloadStartTime=Date.now();if(runDependencies>0){return}preRun();if(runDependencies>0)return;if(Module["calledRun"])return;function doRun(){if(Module["calledRun"])return;Module["calledRun"]=true;if(ABORT)return;ensureInitRuntime();preMain();if(Module["onRuntimeInitialized"])Module["onRuntimeInitialized"]();if(Module["_main"]&&shouldRunNow)Module["callMain"](args);postRun()}if(Module["setStatus"]){Module["setStatus"]("Running...");setTimeout((function(){setTimeout((function(){Module["setStatus"]("")}),1);doRun()}),1)}else{doRun()}}Module["run"]=Module.run=run;function exit(status,implicit){if(implicit&&Module["noExitRuntime"]){return}if(Module["noExitRuntime"]){}else{ABORT=true;EXITSTATUS=status;STACKTOP=initialStackTop;exitRuntime();if(Module["onExit"])Module["onExit"](status)}if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){process["stdout"]["once"]("drain",(function(){process["exit"](status)}));console.log(" ");setTimeout((function(){process["exit"](status)}),500)}else if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL&&typeof quit==="function"){quit(status)}throw new ExitStatus(status)}Module["exit"]=Module.exit=exit;var abortDecorators=[];function abort(what){if(what!==undefined){Module.print(what);Module.printErr(what);what=JSON.stringify(what)}else{what=""}ABORT=true;EXITSTATUS=1;var extra="\nIf this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.";var output="abort("+what+") at "+stackTrace()+extra;if(abortDecorators){abortDecorators.forEach((function(decorator){output=decorator(output,what)}))}throw output}Module["abort"]=Module.abort=abort;if(Module["preInit"]){if(typeof Module["preInit"]=="function")Module["preInit"]=[Module["preInit"]];while(Module["preInit"].length>0){Module["preInit"].pop()()}}var shouldRunNow=true;if(Module["noInitialRun"]){shouldRunNow=false}run()
     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^
  20 | ;(function() {
  21 |  'use strict'
  22 | 
    at Parser._raise (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:742:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:735:17)
    at Parser.raise (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:729:17)
    at ScopeHandler.checkRedeclarationInScope (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:4769:12)
    at ScopeHandler.declareName (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:4749:14)
    at Parser.checkLVal (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9207:22)
    at Parser.parseVarId (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11762:10)
    at Parser.parseVar (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11737:12)
    at Parser.parseVarStatement (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11549:10)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/webpack-demo/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11148:21)
 @ ./src/main.js 4:0-42
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Has anyone found any similar problem or has a hint on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently a couple of issues with importing it via webpack. However they are working on a webpack build:

https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/pull/86

The issue you are running into has to do with how webpack interacts with Emscripten emitted WASM I think, and also that AR.js simply isn't exported as an ES6 Module right now.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I saw the PR on Github and I read it. I think for now I have to wait for the use of that library. Anyway, to find a way around the problem and integrate the AR I found that webXR library is supported in webpack projects and it's easily integrated with three.js. It's not the best solution due to its limited compatibility but it works well with the compatible devices. Here are some examples with related source code: https://threejs.org/examples/#webxr_ar_cones